# Ternary operator blowing up

Tags: coldfusion, ternary-operator, coldfusion-9

I would like some help with my syntax for the following ternary operator (which keeps blowing) in Coldfusion:

```
iif(structKeyExists(session, "newUser") ? session.newUser.planId : 0)
```

It's part of the following model call:

```
user = model("user").new(UUID=createUUID(), planId=iif(structKeyExists(session, "newUser") ? session.newUser.planId : 0));
```

It keeps blowing up, however:

> Parameter validation error for the IIF
>   function. The function takes 3
>   parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f4c.html), the function syntax for `iif` looks like this:

```
IIf(condition, string_expression1, string_expression2)
```

So in your case, you would call it like this:

```
iif(structKeyExists(session, "newUser"), session.newUser.planId, 0)
```

This is different from the ternary operator (`?:`), which is described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ff7) and follows the following syntax:

```
(Boolean expression)? expression1 : expresson2
```

Which, in your case, would look like this:

```
planId=structKeyExists(session, "newUser") ? session.newUser.planId : 0
```

Comment: interesting. If I remove the 'iif' in my original syntax, the function works fine. If I add the iif, your syntax works... I guess I confused iif() with ternary there :/ -- if you could append your answer to account for that, it would really great.